# could not load file or assembly microsoft.office.interop.excel version 15.0.0.0 in windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I am develop a program in VS2012 in Windows 8.

I am reading an Excel file like this.

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileAddress, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

I add Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library to my project.

and my program runs fine in windows 7 and 8 but not in Windows XP. I am getting this error :

> could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.office.interop.excel
>   version 15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublickeyToken=17e9bcce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Edit : I use .Net3.0

Comment: You are just getting an early warning that Office 2013 is not installed on that machine.  Which is unsurprising, it cannot be installed on XP.  Minimum requirement is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that in the Windows XP you may not have the Office 2013 installed (PIA 15) and you may have a version of Excel that is older than 2013 therefore PIAs 14 or lower would only be available on that machine.